# Bulk Auth update transaction in Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

When we upload a CSV of new users, we're wanting to create a Firebase account for that user with a custom claim. Currently we are hitting quota limits exceeded when attempting to upload a CSV with many users. Not entirely sure which quota limit this is but suspect it could be the following -

- New account creation 100 accounts/IP address/hour

The error message:

> Exceeded quota for updating account information.

We are currently using `createUser` and then `setCustomUserClaims`, in a `Promise.all()` to create each user concurrently. This is hosted within a cloud function. Is there a way to do this as a bulk operation so that we do not hit quota limits?

Having investigated `importUsers`, it seems that it by-passes the checks for duplication of email address and the uid; maintaining the integrity of our data is vital.

- This operation is optimized for bulk imports and will ignore checks on `uid`,
- `email` and other identifier uniqueness which could result in duplications.

Are there any elegant solutions to this?

```
await Promise.all(items.map(async user => {
  const userParams = {
    displayName: `${user.firstNames} ${user.lastNames}`,
    phoneNumber: user.mobileNumber,
    email: user.email || ''
  }

  this.logger.debug({ user, role }, 'Creating a new firebase user')
  const member = await this.auth.createUser(userParams)

  this.logger.debug({ member }, 'Attempting to set custom claims for user')
  await this.auth.setCustomUserClaims(member.uid, { role })

  const resetOptions = {
    url: `https://some-url`
  }

  const resetLink = await this.auth.generatePasswordResetLink(user.email, resetOptions)
  const passwordResetData = {
    role,
    link: resetLink,
    firstNames: user.firstNames,
    companyName: 'company name'
  }

  this.logger.debug({ user, passwordResetData }, 'Sending password reset link to user')
  return await this.notificationService.sendPasswordResetLink([user.email], passwordResetData)
}))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be clear about the limit you are reaching.  If there is an error message, share its exact contents.  It will also help if you show the code that you're working with as well.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to figure out a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the admin SDK from either a browser environment, or a non-secure server environment - that's when you hit limitations. If you run it however from a secure environment, the following applies:

> The Firebase Admin SDK provides an API for managing your Firebase Authentication users with elevated privileges. The admin user management API gives you the ability to programmatically complete the following tasks from a secure server environment:
>
> - Create new users without any throttling or rate limiting.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

**Possible solution**

The easiest is to use a [cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). They are serverless functions which you can call either via https or in your app.
You can create a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable):

```
exports.createUsers = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const users = data.user
  // ...
});
```

and pass data in your frontend by calling:

```
functions.httpsCallable("createUsers").call(["users": [])
```

Comment: At the moment, this is running in a cloud function. I believe the throttling is specifically on the `setCustomUserClaims` call but I might be wrong.